# Customizing WCF validation / providing more context when a SerializationException occurs

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, serialization

I am currently working on a WCF service with a REST binding which is expected to be accessed by systems that were not developed in .NET and have no access to the C# data contract. As a result, it is entirely possible for the caller to create valid XML that will cause a SerializationException. For instance, an integer or a date field might be left blank or set to null (i:nil="true").

I would like to be able to return an error message to the user with additional context, telling them exactly what part of the XML could not be deserialized. Is there a clean way to do this? Unfortunately, the SerializationException itself provides no context whatsoever. All I can think of is extracting schemas from teh data conrtact and validating the incoming XML with a schema before attempting to deserialize. This would require me to implement custom serialization. Is there a better way?

An obvious caveat of the schema approach is that it leaves out JSON.

Comment: did you get solution?